# Tox, how to activate the environment and run a command in it?

Tags: python, environment, tox

It's my first time using tox and tried to use tutorials from the internet. This is what my tox.ini file looks like:

```
[tox]
envlist = service
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
install_command = pip install {opts} {packages}
basepython= python3.8

[testenv:service]
envdir = {toxworkdir}/service
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt

setenv =
  PYTHONPATH=.
```

My goal is to activate the environment called service and run console comend on it(sth like: `python __main__.py -someflags`) and I want this command to be run from console. I tried to use `tox -e service -- python __main__.py -someflags` but it doesn't seem to execute the command, just tests (which don't exist).

Comment: `{toxworkdir}/service/bin/python __main__.py -someflags` -- Basically find where the directory of the virtual environment is (`{toxworkdir/service`) then find its Python executable (`bin/python`). This Python executable can be called directly, and it should work well enough in most cases, no need to "activate" the environment.

Comment: In my case it was ```Scripts/python```  but your answer helps me a lot. So the command that works for me: ```{toxworkdir}/service/Scripts/python __main__.py -someflags```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Want to add it as an answer?